# Can you insert HTML in jQuery without string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So the normal way to insert a HTML element is by writing

```
$("#addingRow").before(`
<tr id="customer`+customer.id+`">
<td class="id">`+customer.id+`
</td>
<td class="firstname"><input type="text" value="`+customer.firstname+`"/>
</td>
<td class="lastname"><input type="text" value="`+customer.lastname+`"/>
</td>
<td class="email"><input type="text" value="`+customer.email+`"/>
</td>
<td>
<button onclick="onClickSave(`+customer.id+`)">Save</button>
<button onclick="onClickDelete(`+customer.id+`)">Delete</button>
</td>
</tr>
`)
```

or some function similar to this like (`prepend`, `before`, `...`)

Is there some way to insert the HTML element without using the string tags?
Like in Angular where you only have to write `*ngFor` inside the HTML code.

Comment: any special reason to have like this? Why? Please explain

Comment: `document.createElement('div')`?

Comment: @VicJordan basically we have to write a big test (the matura) and we are not allowed to use angular, but only jquery for it. And writing big html elements that are inserted with strings is a pain.

Comment: It's advisable to avoid putting lengthy HTML string in your JS anyway. If you need to append a large HTML structure, put it in your HTML and set it to `display: none`. Then `clone()`, `append()` and display it when required.

Comment: @vp_arth unfortunatly not enough. i updated the question with a more meaningful example.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan but how exactly can I change the parameters in there then? For example I get data that I need to put in a table - there will be hundrets of rows each with different content.

Comment: You use template strings with concatenation, why?

Comment: @vp_arth because I dont know how to solve this another way?

Comment: @MauriceNino set the attributes on the elements in the cloned content before you append it

Comment: ```...${customer.id}...```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ok that seems like a better option than my version. But still feels a little "hacky" in comparison to the angular functions. thanks tho

Comment: @vp_arth I dont actually think that adds any readability. Might be just me opinion tho

Comment: It's basically what Angular is doing for you under the surface

Comment: Basically, I've done something similar by deploying a `<div id="abc"> </div>`, building within the JS a loooooong string containing all I needed, and then: `document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = My_Long_String;`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan oh ok so I assume that there is no better way than doing so?

Comment: @FDavidov thats exactly what I dont want to do

Comment: So, what you want is to insert piece by piece into the DOM in a loop? If so, I guess you will see significant difference in performance. I use Angular and, in one specific page that may contain up to 100 of records, it takes a couple of seconds to complete rendering. At the  same time, I have an hierarchical menu that I build the way I explained above with nearly 80 entries, and it is finished within a small fraction of a second. Anyway, good luck!!!!

Comment: use .html() method.

Comment: @FDavidov I have used Angular before. I dont know what takes so long in your dev environment, but for me it is exactly as fast. Also I did not ask for the most performant version, but for a version where I dont have to put my html in strings ... and yours does exactly that: only strings

Comment: @yogihosting that would still be a string

Comment: Yes, I got that already. So, the alternative is to loop and insert elements one by one taking into account their hierarchy. I don't see other way (with or without JQuery) you can achieve what you are looking for. Incidentally, That's the way Angular works. In other words, you may try writing your own MINI-Angular.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you mind writing an answer so I can accept it?